# Why does my sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) = 1?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

```
typedef struct {
  double *x;
  int points;
} Polygon;



polygon[cc].points = readobject(polygon[cc].file); //lets say equals 15
polygon[cc].x = (double *) malloc(polygon[cc].points * sizeof(double));

printf("%d\n", sizeof(polygon[cc].x) / sizeof(polygon[cc].x[0]));
//This prints out on 1
```

I've test initializing `x` as `x[100]` and it works then, but shouldn't the `malloc()` call set the struct's array at `x[15]`? Is it just measuring the bytes of two `double`s?

Comment: What would you get with `polygon[cc].x[0]` ? x is not an array...

Comment: Calling `sizeof` on dynamically allocated array would just return the size of pointer in bytes, not the size of whole array.

Comment: `float x[15]` is a very different thing from `float *x = malloc(15 * sizeof(float))` Also, [don't cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code

```
polygon[cc].x
```

is a pointer. by applying `sizeof` on that pointer, what you get is the size of that pointer itself, not the size of the allocated memory pointed by that pointer.

Remember, arrays are not pointers, so if you apply `sizeof` on an array, you'll get the size of the whole array.

In your case, `sizeof(double *)` is equal to `sizeof(double)`, so you get the result as 1.

Comment: If I want the want the size of the whole array, how would I go about calling that instead of a pointer?

Comment: @af3ld As i mentioned, a pointer is not an array. If you allocate memory to a pointer and later you want to get the size of the allocated memory, you cannot get that info from that pointer. You may need to store the allocated size separately and pass that around.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The type of `polygon[cc].x` is `double *`, the type of `polygon[cc].x[0]` is `double`.

It happens that on the computer you tested, pointers and doubles have the same size (8 bytes).

The operator [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) doesn't know anything about the call to `malloc()` (it's none of its business); the `sizeof` expressions in the code you posted are evaluated at the compile time.